# bash find files not of a specified type

Tags: bash

```
/home/ggicci/mydir
 |+ dir_1
 |+ dir_2
 |- file_1.txt
 |- link_1
 |- link_2
```

I want to find all the directories and files but excluding the links. I tried to use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type !l \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec echo {} \;`, but `find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter`. Have I got to run separated commands like `find . -type d ...`, `find . -type f ...`? What if `mydir` contains files of other types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` or `-not` to invert a test comes *before* the test (in your case before `-type`); so, you can write:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -type l \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec echo {} \;
```

or, cleaning up a bit:

```
find   .   -maxdepth 1   ! -type l   ! -iname '.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `find`:

```
file * | grep -v ': .*link' | cut -d: -f1
```